# expect_equal() passes with arguments in one order, fails if arguments are swapped

Tags: r, testthat

When trying to use `testthat::expect_equal()` with two numbers and a tolerance argument, it passes when the arguments are in a certain order, but fails if the two numbers swap argument positions.  I noticed that this function references using `all.equal()` from the base package, and that function also has the pass/fail difference when the arguments are swapped.

I expect the same answer regardless of the order of the first two arguments for both functions.  Please let me know if this is not the right expectation.

```
library(testthat)

# expect_equal does not throw error with one pair of numbers to compare
expect_equal(5, 1, tolerance=1)

# But does when the two numbers are reversed in their arguments
tryCatch(expect_equal(1, 5, tolerance=1), expectation_failure=conditionMessage)
#> [1] "1 not equal to 5.\n1/1 mismatches\n[1] 1 - 5 == -4\n"

# Since this seems to reference `all.equal()` I tried there too, and see an issue:
all.equal(1, 5, tolerance=1)
#> [1] "Mean absolute difference: 4"
all.equal(5, 1, tolerance=1)
#> [1] TRUE

# My session info:
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] testthat_1.0.2
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] backports_1.0.5 R6_2.2.1        magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2  
#>  [5] tools_3.3.3     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.14     crayon_1.3.2   
#>  [9] Rcpp_0.12.10    stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.5   knitr_1.15.1   
#> [13] stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Your tolerance is greater than

```
mean(abs(target-current)) / abs(target)
mean(5 - 1) / 5
4 / 5
0.8
```

So the function returns after the comparison `0.8 < 1` because you've allowed it to pass this tolerance check

---

#### Full answer

The `all.equal()` function has the arguments `target` and `current`

If you delve into the code, when `target` is 5 and `current` is 1 it calculates the mean absolute difference

```
mean(abs(target - current))
# 4
```

Then there is a comparison between the target and the tolerance, which in this case is

```
5 > 1
## TRUE
```

As this is TRUE, it then calculates the relative difference

```
4 / 5 
## 0.8
```

Here, 0.8 is not greater than the tolerance, so it returns out of the function with `TRUE`, i.e

```
all.equal(5, 1, tolerance = 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

So your value of `tolerance` is used in a comparison of the relative difference. Which is why the tolerance defaults to the small value of `1.5e-8`

Here I've taken the relevant code from `all.equal.numeric`, stripped out only the bits of interest so you can see it a bit clearer

```
allEqual <- function (target, current, tolerance = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) 
{
    msg <- NULL
    target <- as.vector(target)
    current <- as.vector(current)
    out <- is.na(target)

    out <- out | target == current

    if (all(out)) 
        return(if (is.null(msg)) TRUE else msg)

    target <- target[!out]
    current <- current[!out]

    xy <- mean(abs(target - current))

    ## THIS BIT HERE vv
    what <- {
        xn <- mean(abs(target))
        # print(paste0("xn: ", xn))
        if (is.finite(xn) && xn > tolerance) {
            #print("xn (target) is GREATER than the tolerance")
            xy <- xy/xn
            #print(paste0("relative difference: ", xy))
            "relative"
        }
        else{
            # print("xn (target) is SMALLER than the tolerance")
            "absolute"
        } 
    }
    ## THIS BIT HERE ^^

    if (is.na(xy) || xy > tolerance) 
        #print("xy is GREATER than the tolerance")
        msg <- c(msg, paste("Mean", what, "difference:", format(xy)))
    if (is.null(msg)) 
        TRUE
    else msg
}
```

---

```
allEqual(5, 1, tolerance = 0.79)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.8"
allEqual(5, 1, tolerance = 0.81)
# [1] TRUE
allEqual(5, 1, tolerance = 1)
# [1] TRUE
allEqual(1, 5, tolerance = 1)
# [1] "Mean absolute difference: 4"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!  I misread/misunderstood the `all.equal()` documentation, and thought that if `scale=NULL` (default), then absolute comparisons were used.  This is only true if the `target` and `current` are near 0.  In my actual code, I changed to use `expect_true()` and compare the abs difference against a set tolerance to accomplish my need, rather `expect_equal()` with a misunderstood tolerance value.